# pass matlab matrices to DLL that accepting pointers?

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, matrix

Are there some good ways to pass large block matlab matrices to DLL functions?

The problem is, we get a compiled DLL file without source code, so creating a mex is not possible, the DLL functions accept pointers as matrices inputs, yet it seems that matlab dont support pointers passing to DLL (if I understand correctly).

Is there some way to work around this, many thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need to `mex` an interface from matlab to the dll - a function you can call from matlab that subsequently calls the dll function.  You don't have to `mex` the dll itself.

Comment: Yes, thats a solution but the problem is this DLL will be called very freqenctly, so by channelling mex, the overheads will be huge. but thanks anyway, so there is not any simple way to pass pointers there? cannot believe matlab dont offer such basic functionalities when they themselves use mkl and other external libraries extensively...

Comment: You can see if [libpointer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libpointer.html) does what you want...

Comment: That function looks very useful, many thanks!

Comment: @tmpearce I would recommend you to post your suggestion, otherwise this question will remain unanswered.